# Contar número de "sim" em cada linha de uma Tabela no R

Tags: r, for

Considere essa tabela como exemplo

```
a<-c("sim","não","sim","sim")
b<-c("sim","sim","sim","sim")
c<-c("sim","não","sim","não")
d<-c("não","não","sim","sim")
dados<-data.frame(a,b,c,d)
```

Eu preciso de um vetor com a quantidade de "sim" de cada linha. Tentei criar usando um for dentro de outro for, mas não consegui.
Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: [Esta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27850189/8245406) deve ser a mais fácil e rápida maneira de fazer o que pede: `dados$cont <- rowSums(dados == "sim")`.